# How can I extract a specific table from a website that has multipe tables in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a table from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018.html. The table I want is the (Team per game stats). This webpage has multiple tables, and when I try to extract the tables from it, it gives the first two tables from the page.

How can I get the table I want using R? I mentioned below the code I used

```
library(rvest)


url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018.html"

# read the link 

html <-read_html(url)


tables <- html %>% html_table(fill =TRUE)

View(tables)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is commented out. You can grab the comments with xpath then grab the table you want

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018.html')

df <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()') %>%
  html_text() %>%  
  paste(collapse = '') %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node('#team-stats-per_game') %>%
  html_table()
```